# Determining which subpattern was matched when using '|' operator in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression that is pieced together with a '|', aka OR operator, which is comprised of smaller sub-patterns.  I'm trying to determine which sub-pattern was matched, but the RegExp engine will only give me the entire expression.

Examples:

Here is my compiled (approximate), pieced expression (massively simplified for comprehension:

```
/^somestring-(\w+)$|^notherstring-(\d+)-(\w+)$|^laststring-(\w+)-([a-f])$/g
```

Here is the input text:

```
laststring-eof
```

So in my matches array, I see a few indexes with "undefined values" (since there are a couple of attempted matches before that don't match the entire expression), but also I get my match "eof".

This is all great, gives me most of what I want.  What I'm NOT getting that I need, is to know that the sub-pattern that was matched was "^laststring-(\w+)$", or at the least, to know that is was the third sub-pattern in the main expression.  I can't rely on the length of the match array, since each sub-pattern can have an indefinite number of match groups.

I tried regexp.lastIndex, but that property only gives me the last match within the sub-pattern, not the offset of the sub-pattern within the entire expression.

Comment: I suspect you need to call match with each of the 3 different regexs

Comment: @rpaskett first fix the unbalanced pairs of parentheses `()`

Comment: Can you not simply look at the captured match to determine this (i.e. does it begin with `somestring`, `notherstring`, etc.)?

Comment: OP stated that the example was "massively simplified"

Comment: I currently am doing 3 different regex matches (in the case of the example), but as I mentioned, the number of sub-patterns is indefinite, it could end up being 100+.  I want to think that doing 100 matches on smaller regexes would be slower than matching one much larger expression.  I could be wrong, but I'd still like to find out how to accomplish the task I've proposed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this would work, but I think if you put () brackets around each of the subgroups you should be able to check which of them is non-null if the expression matches, and in that way you can see which pattern matches.

In your case that would create 3 additional sub-groups, and if I count correctly it would be something like this:

first group = first sub-pattern

second group = first matching group in first sub-pattern

third group = second sub-pattern

fourth group and fifth group = the sub-patterns in the second sub-pattern

sixth = third sub-group

So you check the first, third and sixth matching group for which one is non-null and that's your matching pattern.

Comment: I actually went down that road, and it is definitely a possibility, but I couldn't get it quite right. It gets messy when each sub-pattern has different numbers of matches their returning. If you have an example, please share.

Comment: My idea was more that you'd always know which matching group corresponds to the sub-pattern you search for, but I'm not sure I understood your problem correctly if there's a problem with that. I figure if you construct the regex you can always count the number of matching groups you put in and see which ones correspond to the whole pattern. And then you can just test each of them whether they matched or not. I'm not sure why the numbers of matches the sub-patterns return are a problem.

Comment: So what I meant is something like, you have the matcher, you call matcher.matches() and then you check with if (matcher.group(index_of_first_sub-pattern) != null) if the sub-pattern matched. I'm not sure why the number of sub-patterns returned makes that difficult. Or is there a problem with knowing the index of a sub-pattern group?

Comment: I think the problem is that groups are numbered in a flat manner based on the opening parenthesis position, so you can't know what number the second top-level group is without knowing how many subgroups the first top-level group has.  Presumably, OP is concatenating together a number of alternates which aren't literals, and doesn't want to scan each one counting parentheses..

Comment: But I really think there's technically not really an alternative. I think it would help to know more about how he generates the pattern as a whole. There should always be some way to count how many sub-groups there are, in the worst case I think he could construct the whole pattern as a string and then search how many sub-groups are in between after constructing the pattern.

Comment: @AndreasMüller The patterns are registered through a function, and then joined together programmatically. But, that doesn't really matter, since I think the problem has been sufficiently explained. I agree with you that doing an additional match on the sub-pattern itself might be the only way to accomplish the task (at least in a way that is sufficiently simple).  Too much complexity and any performance advantage to executing the compound regex will be completely lost.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to know which branch was matches, is to look at which groups are present in the result array:

```
s = "laststring-eof";
p = /^somestring-(\w+)$|^notherstring-(\d+)-(\w+)$|^laststring-(\w+)-([a-f])$/g;
m = p.exec(s);
if (m[1] !== undefined) { /* first branch */ }
else if (m[2] !== undefined) { /* second branch */ }
else if (m[4] !== undefined) { /* last branch */ }
```

When the different branches are pieced together from other patters, you'll need to count the number of capture-groups in each:

```
function countCapturingGroups(regexp) {
    var count = 0;
    regexp.source.replace(/\[(?:\\.|[^\\\]])*\]|\\.|(\()(?!\?)/g,
        function (full, capturing) {
            if (capturing) count++;
        });
    return count;
}
```

For branches that have zero capture-groups, you could add an empty capture:

```
p = /^somestring-(\w+)$|()^nocaptures$/g;
```

This could also be done for other braches, if they are not guaranteed to include the first group.

A longer example:

```
function MultiRegExp(patterns)
{
    this.patterns = patterns;
    this.combined = new RegExp(patterns.map(function (p) {
        return "()" + p.source;
    }).join("|"));
    this.numcaptures = patterns.map(countCapturingGroups);
    this.start = [1];
    for (var i = 1; i < numcaptures.length; i++) {
        this.start[i] = this.start[i-1] + this.numcaptures[i-1] + 1;
    }
}

MultiRegExp.prototype.exec = function (str) {
    var m = this.combined.exec(str);
    if (!m) return;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.numcaptures.length; i++) {
        var offset = this.start[i];
        if (m[offset] !== undefined) {
            var result = [i,m[0]];
            for (var j = 1; j <= this.numcaptures[i]; j++) {
                result.push(m[offset + j]);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
};

var p = new MultiRegExp([
    /^somestring-(\w+)$/,
    /^notherstring-(\d+)-(\w+)$/,
    /^laststring-(\w+)-([a-f])$/,
    /^nocaptures$/
]);

p.exec("somestring-abc"); // -> [0, "somestring-abc", "abc"]
p.exec("nocaptures"); // -> [3, "nocaptures"]
```

Comment: This won't work, because it assumes that each sub-pattern will have the exact number of matches as shown in the example.  The pattern changes depending on certain things.  This is also possible:
/^new-somestring-(\w+)-(\D{2})-(\d)$|^oldstring-(\d+)-(\w+)$|^examplestring-(\w+)$/g

Comment: @rpaskett The example should demonstrate better what I meant.